# extract all <a> tags from content

Tags: php, html

I want to extract all links inside some pages with their link text to show in a block. I 've tried regex but it doesn't get correct result because the  tags don't have a fix pattern,they have various attribute.I use PHP.

How can i do it?

Comment: You do **not** want to use regexes for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

like :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    // do something with $a->textContent
}
```

Comment: thank you.i add it to my code and get this error: :  Fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in

Comment: what u pass to loadHTML function ? $string need to be the content of the html

Comment: it is html.the problem was i did echo $a not $a->textContent.

Comment: I need the href value too.how can i get it?

Answer (score 2):

You can try getting specified tags using [PHP:DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php). Here is an example:

inside page.html

```
<a href="#">link1</a>
<a href="#">link2</a>
<a href="#">link3</a>
```

and this is your PHP code:

```
<?php 

$src = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$src->formatOutput = true;
$src->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$src->load('page.html');

$links = $src->getElementsByTagName('a');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using DOM and getElementsByTagName()?

http://php.net/domdocument

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php