# Regex for detecting hyperlink (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [extract all <a> tags from content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568917/extract-all-a-tags-from-content)

i am fetching website contents using curl (PHP) and then perform a check if it contains a string.
I would like to check if this string is a hyperlink or not. Does anybody know the correct regex/code to perform this?

Many Thanks,

J

Comment: do you mean "contains an URL" or "contains an html hyperlink <a src="....">xxxx</a>"  ?

Comment: [Don't do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 4):

You want to use PHP's [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function. For example: `filter_var('http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can i use the filter_var to find if the url is a hyperlink i.e it contains <a href. So the first thing is to check whether the url is in the content/string then if the url is a hyperlink.

Comment: In that case you probably want to combine filter_var with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568917/extract-all-a-tags-from-content as suggested by @Quentin above

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When i try as advised in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568917/extract-all-a-tags-from-content i get the following error: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: ID top already defined in Entity, line: 41 
I am passing a string directly from curl_exec into loadHTML, do i have to do any conversion before that?

Comment: That means you're trying to parse invalid HTML. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702799/php-parsing-invalid-html for some code that shows how you can fix this error